# How to get the values of this array of objects in php

Tags: php

Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[color] => #5fa4c4
)

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [color] => #147b5c
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [color] => #ce0384
    )
```

)

Comment: thats a very basic question. u can use a lot of method,. one of which is using foreach, https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

There’s a few ways you could do it. For, While, Foreach Loop etc. I’d personally use foreach as it requires less code.

```
<?php
// Array Data
$array = [["#5fa4c4"], ["#147b5c"], ["#ce0384"]];

// Loop Through Array Data
foreach($array as $data){
  $colour = $data[0];
  echo $colour;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with `foreach` loop as below code

```
$colors = array( 
            array("color" => "#5fa4c4"),
            array("color" => "#147b5c"),
            array("color" => "#ce0384"),            
        );

foreach($colors as $color):
    echo $color['color'].'<br>'; //final colors values
endforeach;
```

output is

```
#5fa4c4
#147b5c
#ce0384
```